# How do I route each subdomain to matching solution folders in azure websites?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, webforms, azure-web-app-service

I'm currently have the naked domain mydomain.com pointed to my azure website. The www CNAME is also pointed to my azure website (**main mvc app**). But the problem is, I also created several subdomains **school.mydomain.com**, **work.mydomain.com** and **personal.mydomain.com** and I'd like them to point to different solution folders I have under my solution. Some projects are MVC, some are Webforms.

My solution structure is the following:

```
{
   "solution" : [
      "main mvc app",
      "school solution folder",
      "work solution folder",
      "personal solution folder"
   ]
}
```

I'd like to access:

- **main mvc app** from mydomain.com and www.mydomain.com
- **school solution folder** from xxx.mydomain.com
- **work solution folder** from yyy.mydomain.com
- **personal solution folder** from zzz.mydomain.com

The reason I want to achieve this is because main mvc app is my website, and school folder, work folder and personal folder are all just solution folders that will later be populated with mvc, webforms and other projects.

For example school work would be accessed from **school.mydomain.com/homework1** (webforms app), **school.mydomain.com/homework2** (mvc app) and **school.mydomain.com/homework3** (webforms app).

Doing this from cpanel or enkompass was easy. Just create a folder, point a subdomain to it and bam. But in azure it's a whole other deal.

I'm currently routing **school**, **work** and **personal** subdomains succesfully to a controller, and have even considered using areas, but this will only work for MVC sub projects, not web forms projects. And all my personal and school projects are webforms.

Any ideas?

Comment: You should post the route config file!

Answer (score 0):

You can define **routes** for the `WebForm` App as well. I'm suppousing that you have a full functional `ASP.NET Hybrid`WebForms + MVC` working and you can acess this, then:

To configure routes for `WebForms` (in the application) take a look here [How to: Define Routes for `WebForms` Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668177%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) or [URL Routing with ASP.NET 4 Web Forms](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/10/13/url-routing-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx)

If you dont have the `WebForms` working with `MVC`, I recommend this read: [Integrating ASP.NET MVC 3 into existing upgraded ASP.NET 4 Web Forms applications](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntegratingASPNETMVC3IntoExistingUpgradedASPNET4WebFormsApplications.aspx) from Scott Helseman.